# Appropriate place for questions about mechanical 3D modeling

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What's the best place to ask questions about designing mechanical components using CAD software? I see the "Blender" site, but that seems geared just for artistic usage.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you're asking about

Comment: @random, I want advice on how to design mechanical parts that will be cut from a stock sheet and then bent into shape. Specifically, I'd like to know how to incorporate the "bend" into the design of the 2D part.

Comment: There is no site for that currently.  A few attempts have been tried to make such a site, but never made out of beta.

Comment: [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) is up and running.

Answer (score 2):

There is yet another [CAD proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad) on Area 51, started six days before this question was asked, I believe. There was at least one other one before it, but it eventually died. You could definitely ask there, though of course it would not be answered (at least not until the proposal reaches beta, if that ever happens).

[Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) is in beta, I'm happy to say, and I see that [you have an account there](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/175/cerin?tab=topactivity). We started [a meta discussion](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/are-questions-about-engineering-software-on-topic-what-questions) early on about whether or not CAD questions are on topic or not. The answer seems to be "yes" for some questions (read the meta post for more information), and we have a [computer-aided-design](/questions/tagged/computer-aided-design) tag, with five questions (as of the posting). You can ask there, or perhaps first ask in [Engineering chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/engineering).

Additionally, [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) has now entered private beta.